# Can we bind pagefactory with assertions in selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have written the following code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class CreateGroup_Page {
    public class CreateGroup{
        public CreateGroup(WebDriver driver){
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

    @FindBy(linkText = "CREATE A GROUP")
    public WebElement menu_createGroup;
    HOW CAN I ADD Assert.assertTrue WITH THE ABOVE PAGE OBJECT FACTORY.


    //public WebElement menu_createGroup(WebDriver driver){
        //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("CREATE A          GROUP"));
        //Assert.assertTrue(menu_createGroup.isDisplayed());

    //return element;
    //}             
//}
```

In the above case when I try with to call assertions with pagefactory objects, I cannot do so. However if I define seperate class and when I call it works fine as above. Please help me in how to call assertions with pagefactory.

Comment: You are doing it right , it should work. Whats the error , you are getting?

Comment: @Juhi. Here I wanted to integrated with pagefactory object that I defined. If I don't create a method and when I directly write @FindBy(linkText = "CREATE A GROUP")
    public WebElement menu_createGroup;Assert.assertTrue(menu_createGroup.isDisplayed()); then it was showing exception. As per Karthik's advise I have created a seperate method and calling in the action class seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In page factory the element is a variable which you have done correctly. Use an assert in method which I do not see in your code.

See this link for ex: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Comment: your answer is perfect.

Comment: cannot we create without creating method and directly calling assert like this Assert.assertTrue(menu_createGroup.isDisplayed());

Comment: No sivasankar. You must do it inside a method because asserts are usually part of @Test.

Comment: Fine Karthik. Thank you.